# EF 5.0 ForeignKey relationship

Tags: .net, entity-framework, foreign-key-relationship

I have TableA with following columns

Id,
orgid,
client id,
......
etc.10 columns

And i have table B with the below columns
tableAid,(Is foreign key from table A)
orgresponseA
........ 16 columns

In simple Table B is an extension for Table A.

I am trying to add relationship in `TableBConfiguration` but I am not seeing foregin Key property.

```
HasRequired(p => p.TableA);
            .HasForeignKey????? 
            ToTable("dbo.TableB");
```

How to set **foreign key** relationship with Table A and Table B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a foreign key property to your entity class:

```
public class TableBClass
{
    // ...
    public int TableAId { get; set; }
    public TableA TableA { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

And then use the mapping:

```
HasRequired(b => b.TableA).WithMany().HasForeignKey(b => b.TableAId);
```

If you don't want to have the FK property in your class you can use instead:

```
HasRequired(b => b.TableA).WithMany().Map(m => m.MapKey("TableAId"));
```

Comment: Thanks Slauma it works. I used the second solution without ID key. Whenever i insert data into TableB its inserting double rows with TableA Id duplication. I also have PK on TableB. Am i missing anything here..??

Comment: @Ducati007: That's likely not a problem of the mapping. Unwished duplication on Insert often occurs when the related entity is not attached to the context. I suggest that you create a new question and show the code that causes the duplication.